# Current navigation - I want to hide pages but the control is disabled?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm trying to hide pages from being displayed in the current `Navigation` bar.

I've tried two Options:

1. Go to `Site Settings` -> `Navigation` -> `Current Navigation` then try and untick the Show pages button. However, this button is disabled for me.
2. On the home page, click `edit links` and try and remove them manually. However, they do not delete. They are in fact undeletable.

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: What permissions you have on site?

Comment: I'm a site collection Administrator

Answer (score 1):

The pages links cannot be hide or deleted one by one. You have to show all or hide all. for this you can do this

- Go to `Site Settings` -> `Navigation`, and in the top you will find some options for `global navigation` then `current navigation`. here In the `structural navigation` option you can untick `show pages` option.

Comment: Thanks but as I said in my Point 1) - I've tried this method but the button for 'Show pages' is disabled. I cannot click it at all. Any idea why it would not be working for me?

Comment: you may not have the permission for do this

Comment: I'm a site collection adimistrator

Comment: Is this for the site you are an admin? or the parent site??